# CustomCell Reference Lost

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have working in a tableView which supports both orientations.Let me explain the whole scenario what problem I have faced.

1. I have shown one cover Image , one progress bar , button and couple of labels in a tableView row by using customCell when iPhone is in portrait view.
2. I have shown two images , two progress bars and button and labels, In simple words I have shown two records in a row in landscape View

**Problem**

- When I have start downloading in portrait view and changed its orientation then the reference of custom cell at particular index is lost.
- If I have clicked on 5 row to download some file the array index is 4 in this case and indexPath.row is also 4, But in landscape mode array index is still 4 but indexPath.row is [array count]/2 if [array count]%2==0 otherwise it is [array count]/2 +1

Comment: Please check your conditions....you write here your indexPath.row is [array count]/2 if [array count]%2 == 0 its fine...but if your [array count] = 3 then your condition is [array count]/2 + 1....means 3/2+1 = ????..did u get....

Comment: how to check the conditions without losing the reference of customCell for that particular index?

Comment: here check like that.....if your array count = 5 then in check it like if ([array count]%2 != 0) then condition will be ([array count] - 1)/2+1. so if count is 5 then you get (5-1)/2+1 = 3 (indexpath.row)..

Comment: Getting indexPath is not an issue issue is that if I have start downloading and then current cell is 5 in portrait its progress bar continuously updated when I have changed its orientation to landScape mode the reference of previous cell is lost and app is crashed in this scenerio

Answer (score 0):

For landscape mode here check like that.....
if your array count = 5 then in check it like

```
 if ([array count]%2 != 0) 
  {
     indexpath.row = ([array count] - 1)/2 + 1 
   }
```

So for example if count is 5 then you get (5-1)/2+1 = 3

And when you download any thing then that time add that reference in an array and in viewwillApper() method just check one condition that if your reference array count is grater then zero, get that reference from array and put it in your view at respective position....